# Different HttpStatusCode for different clients in Nancy

Tags: asp.net, nancy, dhc

After navigate to `http://localhost:57645` code below returns 200 (OK) for [DHC by Restlet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dev-http-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm) and 500 (InternalServerError) for "Chrome Browser".

```
public class SampleModule : Nancy.NancyModule
{
    public SampleModule()
    {
        Get["/"] = _ =>
        {
            return Negotiate
                .WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK)
                .WithModel(10);
        };
}
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you're experiencing in the first example is expected. The browser is requesting `text/html`

`Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8`

Nancy is attempting to locate a view based on the type `10`, since `10` is a type of `Int32`, Nancy is trying to find a view called `Int32` since its trying to response with a View, since that's what the browser asked for.

The Dev Client you're using in Chrome is most likely sending a request for JSON by default which is why it appears to be working.

You can read more about this here:

http://www.philliphaydon.com/2013/04/nancyfx-revisiting-content-negotiation-and-apis-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

Found it! In my case best to use

```
return Response.AsJson(10);
```